# Why Pycharm can't run code with relative imports?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-import, relative-import

My package structure:

```
root_pkg
root_pkg/__init__.py # empty
root_pkg/game
root_pkg/game/__init__.py # empty
root_pkg/game/game1.py
root_pkg/utils
root_pkg/utils/__init__.py # empty
root_pkg/utils/lib.py
```

`root_pkg/game/game1.py` contains:

```
"""File root_pkg/game/game1.py"""

from ..utils import lib
```

that does not issue any errors

Running this in pycharm however:

```
C:\_\Python363-64\python.exe C:/Dropbox/eclipse_workspaces/python/test_imports/root_pkg/game/game1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Dropbox/eclipse_workspaces/python/test_imports/root_pkg/game/game1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..utils import lib
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Process finished with exit code 1
```

However, content and source paths are added to python path in the run configuration:

[image]

So why Pycharm can't run this? Shouldn't it add the project folder to the PYTHONPATH? Is it the correct style of imports to use?

**EDIT**: changing the working dir in run config to `C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\python\test_imports\` results in same error:

```
C:\_\Python363-64\python.exe C:/Dropbox/eclipse_workspaces/python/test_imports/root_pkg/game/game1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Dropbox/eclipse_workspaces/python/test_imports/root_pkg/game/game1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..utils import lib
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Note it runs fine from the command line using the `-m` switch, so PyCharm is correct in not erroring out:

```
C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\python\test_imports>C:\_\Python363-64\python.exe -m root_pkg.game.game1
```

Changing this to an absolute import `from utils import lib` displays an error in pycharm and also fails in the command line:

```
C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\python\test_imports>C:\_\Python363-64\python.exe root_pkg/game/game1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "root_pkg/game/game1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from utils import lib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\python\test_imports>C:\_\Python363-64\python.exe -m root_pkg.game.game1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\_\Python363-64\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\_\Python363-64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\python\test_imports\root_pkg\game\game1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from utils import lib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

Comment: Compare the directory from which you executed the script in the command line to the "working directory" in Pycharm's configuration settings screen

Comment: See my edit please - had tried that @DeepSpace

Comment: To downvoter - this is a pycharm tagged question - it is not about the relative import per se

Comment: I've tried `from utils import lib` and it seemed to be working well. Did you mark either `game` or `utils` in any way? (by marking I mean f.e. Sources Root)

Comment: @Kamil well I did now mark `root_pkg` as source folder and this solved it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding the `root_pkg` to source folders made the run configuration work (and PyCharm not error out on absolute import).

[image]

Printing the sys.path shows that PyCharm added the absolute path to `root_pkg` there while it does not add subfolders of content root. What confused me was that it resolved the relative import right while it errored on the absolute one, while both couldn't be resolved at runtime.